# Save, Close and Re-Open "ThisWorkbook"

Tags: vba, excel

I need to Save, Close and Re-Open "ThisWorkbook".
The code should be something like this:

```
Sub reopen()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

wb.Save
wb.Close
wb.Open

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, there is no such command "wb.Open", and once I "wb.Close", the code stops :)

P.S. It should be a part of a bigger one, which gives an error "91" if the workbook isn't saved-closed and reopened...

Comment: Actually there is a problem, since `wb = ThisWorkbook`, when you close it, code execution always breaks (since you close workbook from which code runs). `I need such a code, as it should be a part of a bigger one, which gives an error "91" if the workbook isn't saved-closed and reopened...` - I suggest you to modify your code logic. If you show your code, maybe I could help you

Comment: I would do that, if I knew what was wrong with the "current" logic. There is something happening, when the wb is closed and then reopened, that is not happening if the wb is only saved... It is some sort of "Update" or "Restart", but I don't know how to simulate it with a code.

Comment: Ok, show please your full code and line where you get an error.I'll try to revise it

Comment: There are exactly 989 lines of code, and about 20 "Subs", working in different combinations. Even if I share the code, it wouldn't make sense without the excel file itself. I'll be glad to share it to you on your e-mail or smth...

Comment: `989 lines of code` - wow, it's really big! Maybe you can locate somehow a problem and post only relevant code?

Comment: You could use Application.Ontime to schedule a sub to run which will reopen Excel if closed. However, it does seem like a 'dirty' hack!

Comment: I tried to do that with my previous question, but the answer you gave me only tells the user that the "value" is missing. I need to save-close-open the file, so that the value would appear. I believe that the problem is coming from either copy/paste of range or renaming a sheet...

Comment: @ ooo : I love 'dirty' hacks :) Could you give an example of how to use it in the case above ? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could use a procedure in you [personal workbook](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm) to close the file and reopen it?

Comment: What's the point of opening and closing and then immediately reopening the workbook?  Perhaps we can address that logic to give you a workable solution.  For instance, is there code in your Workbook_Open event that you need to run?

Comment: I need such a code, as it should be a part of a bigger one, which gives an error "91" if the workbook isn't saved-closed and reopened. There is something happening, when the wb is closed and then reopened, that is not happening if the wb is only saved... It is some sort of "Update" or "Restart", but I don't know how to simulate it with a code.

Comment: So is there some code in your Workbook_Open() or Workbook_Close() event that needs to be run?  If there is, you can split that out to another module (and / or sub) and then call that rather than having to explicitly open and close the workbook.

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub reopen()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim pth As String
pth = wb.FullName

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Application.Workbooks.Open(pth)
wb.Close (True)

End Sub
```

Comment: This code does the job of saving-closing-reopening, but the other code still gives an error. FML

Comment: Does this still work if a single excel file is open in two computer, for example, in a shared folder in a network?

Comment: You can use a non-string command with OnTime?

Comment: @johnywhy nope, have to make it into a string

Comment: I get an error telling me it can't find the macro 'Application.Workbooks.Open("path\to\file")'. If I put the open function in a macro, same error. Might work if I didn't have to pass the file name as an argument, but it defeats the point.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your goals there are two possible options that I know of right off hand.

First: Save, Close and ReOpen from the same routine:

```
Sub SaveCloseReOpen()
Dim strCMD As String

strCMD = "CMD /C PING 10.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL & Excel.exe " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34)

ThisWorkbook.Save
Shell strCMD, vbNormalFocus
If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
    Application.Quit
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If

End Sub
```

Basically the workbook will save itself then run a Shell CMD to Ping a Non-Routable IP waiting for 5 seconds (You can use Timeout or something else if you prefer) then it will Execute Excel.exe and reopen the the workbook.  Depending on how many workbooks are open it will Close the Excel Application or just the workbook...  Though this method will open the Excel Application in a Separate Instance.  If you want the same instance, then I would use the Application.OnTime Method.

Second: Save, Close from one routine But ReOpen through the Workbook Deactivate Event:

In the Workbook Module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    If bClose_ReOpen Then
        Shell "CMD /C PING 10.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL & Excel " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
        If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
            Application.Quit
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in a Regular Module:

```
Option Explicit
Public bClose_ReOpen As Boolean

Sub SaveCloseReOpen()
    bClose_ReOpen = True
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Similar to the First Routine; however, this routine will execute the Shell Run command (via Public Boolean Variable) after the Workbook has mostly closed...  If you have any Before_Save or Before_Close Events, they will run first as the Workbook_Deactivate Routine is the last one processed before the workbook actually closes.

You can always change the vbNormalFocus for the Shell CMD to vbHide if you prefer.