# VBA - Close "ThisWorkbook", and re-open after Delay

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains a Macro that checks the workbook out from our SharePoint server, updates it, and then should check it back in.  Afterwards, it should remain open for the user review and possibly execute other updates.  The main problem I have is that the ".checkin" method closes out the Workbook, terminating the macro before it can re-open the workbook.  I had found a proposed solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380886/8858822 , however I have encountered a problem with how Application.OnTime operates.

If I attempt to use the Application.Workbook.Open procedure as an argument for the Application.OnTime method, as suggested by the link above, the .Open procedure gets called immediately, without waiting the desired delay.  In this scenario, the workbook has not been checked-in and closed yet, causing an error:

```
Sub TestSub()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim FPath As String
FPath = wb.FullName    

Workbooks.CheckOut (FPath)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'execute workbook updates
'''''''''''''''''''''''''

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath)

wb.CheckIn

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Is there a reason that Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath) executes immediately, instead of waiting the specified 10 seconds?  If I can delay that execution by 10 seconds, the code would execute correctly.

I noticed that if instead of directly opening the file, I call one the macros in the file, it does wait the desired 10 seconds. This allows for the file to first be checked in and closed, then re-opens it and executes the specified macro.

```
Sub TestSub()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim FPath As String
FPath = wb.FullName    

Workbooks.CheckOut (FPath)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'execute workbook updates
'''''''''''''''''''''''''

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), " ' file address & name '!OtherMacroName "

wb.CheckIn

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

With this code, the file is checked in, closes, and then after 10 seconds reopens the file and runs the macro. Unfortunately, due to trust center settings I believe, I cannot directly call macros from workbooks saved on our SharePoint server, and this code generates an permissions error.  If I relocate the file to my personal or our network drive, it executes without error.  I have not been able to resolve the SharePoint permissions issue, even after following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21175812/8858822 .

If I can understand why the Application.Workbooks.Open procedure operates immediately, while the macro call procedure waits the desired 10 seconds, when each is an argument used by Application.OnTime, I believe the code would work as desired.  If there is a way to call the macro within the closed workbook after 10 seconds, I presume there must be some way of just opening the workbook after the 10 seconds?  Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: It wont solve the problem you are having, but make sure that when `ThisWorkbook` closes, your `Application` doesn't close. If it does, your `Application.OnTime` wont run, since the host process (`Application`) has finished.

Answer (score 0):

`OnTime` takes the **name** of a subroutine as its argument. You need to create a new routine for `OnTime` to call (it doesn't actually have to do anything if all you need is the workbook reopened).

Comment: Thanks.  I run into an issue that I believe has to do with it being a file on our SharePoint server.  It successfully opens the file, but then generates an error message saying that the macro could not be run, and either does not exist or all macros are disabled. When the file is saved locally there is no problem.  Is there an alternative method to opening the workbook, or at least suppressing the warning? the normal Application.DisplayAlerts method does not seem to work either setting it before the .OnTime call, or in the called subroutine, as excel returns an error before entering it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason that Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath) executes
>   immediately, instead of waiting the specified 10 seconds? If I can
>   delay that execution by 10 seconds, the code would execute correctly.

Yes. The answer you linked is incorrect.

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), SecondArgument
```

The `SecondArgument` is the name of a subroutine to call.

What you're doing when you put `Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath)` in `SecondArgument` is opening the workbook, then returning a reference to the workbook, in the same way you would go:

```
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath)
```

Put differently, when you do this...

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath)
```

... you're actually doing this:

```
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FPath)
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), wb
```

So that answers your question, but to solve your problem...

From [this link](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/57868-close-and-reopen-workbook-from-macro-stored-inside-workbook?t=66417), there's some sort of dirty workaround where the key is apparently to call the `Application.OnTime` method a moment **before** you close the workbook (check in the workbook in your case):

```
Sub CloseMe()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "OpenMe"
    ThisWorkbook.Close ' check in
End Sub

Sub OpenMe()
    ' literally does nothing
End Sub
```

So Excel knows to run the `OpenMe` method in 2 seconds' time, and it is that act of attempting to run the `OpenMe` method that actually re-opens the workbook.

---

You can test this by having two workbooks:

`E:\Documents\Book3.xlsm` has the following code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    MsgBox "test"

End Sub
```

`E:\Documents\Book2.xlsm` has the following code:

```
Sub OpenAnotherWorkbook()

    Application.Run "'E:\Documents\Book3.xlsm'!TestMe"

End Sub
```

Making sure that `E:\Documents\Book3.xlsm` is currently **closed**, we run `OpenAnotherWorkbook` from `E:\Documents\Book2.xlsm`.

It will open `E:\Documents\Book3.xlsm` and run `TestMe`.