# Error with VBA "Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), Workbooks.Open(pth)"

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

I am trying to programmatically close and reopen the same excel workbook.  I have started with code I found in an old article I found on this site ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379546/save-close-and-re-open-thisworkbook/22380886#22380886) for reference).

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), Workbooks.Open(pth)
ThisWorkbook.Close (True)
```

As coded above, `Workbooks.Open(pth)` executes immediately.   *That is not the desired behavior and actually fails in different ways depending on whether `(pth)` is already opened or whether it represents some other random closed workbook).*

I have tried the following (adding quotes to the second parameter):

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Workbooks.Open(pth)"
ThisWorkbook.Close (True)
```

Although this does allow the Ontime method to fully execute, it treats the second parameter (now in quotes) as a macro in the existing workbook, so that after the 5 seconds specified, the following is reported:

[Image capture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTVXN.png)

So I am looking for instruction on how I can replace `Workbooks.Open(pth)` with an actual string argument that the Ontime method is expecting and will result in the workbook specified in `(pth)` being opened after the specified time elapses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do what you want:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    'Schedule `CallMe` to run in 5 seconds, with an argument
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "'CallMe ""Message Here""'"
    ThisWorkbook.Close True
End Sub

'This will be called from OnTime: if the workbook is closed 
'  it will be re-opened
Sub CallMe(msg)
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you @Tim.  Your example helped me understand more what Ontime is doing.  To clarify, I don't want to run a macro or routine in my re-opened workbook.   I simply want it to re-open the workbook wihtout trying to run anything other than the Workbook_Open) code.

Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: btw I did get your sample working in my project calling one of my own routines.   So I realize I could simply add a "do_nothing()" routine and call that as a workaround.   

As it turns out, my design is flawed. I intended to use Ontime to reopen a workbook as a workaround to solve another issue.  But in my case it won't work.  I will post that issue on this board if I don't get a response elsewhere already posted, and reference that post from here if I do.

Still would like to know if Ontime can reopen a workbook without calling a specific macro in the reopened workbook

Comment: You will need at least a "do nothing" Sub/Function to call.  You can pass a dummy name instead, but that will give you an error when the workbook re-opens, saying it can't find the sub you specified.  If you have a Personal Macro Workbook then the sub could be in that workbook and it could re-open any workbook given the path as an argument.

Comment: After more testing of your solution, I see that the macro that is run by Ontime actually executes BEFORE the Workbook_Open() code, which surprised me, but gives me a way to use this as the workaround I was looking for anyway!    Now I will set a boolean in a macro executed by Ontime which can be tested by the Workbook_Open() code and execute accordingly.   This allows me to reopen a workbook as a workaround to another issue I'm having and still looking for a solution to (which I'll post here if not answered elsewhere first."

Comment: Thanks for that comment on the dummy routine.   I tried to mark your first answer as solution but I don't have enough posts/points to do so.  But you got me where I needed to be and answered the question.   THANK YOU!